# Installed app doesn't run(gitkraken)

Tags: software-installation, debian

I installed the gitKraken app and it appears on my app list, but when I press the icon and trying to run the app it doesn't run properly.
when I run the command  `ps -ax` it appears on the list of the running tasks.

any idea of what I can do?

****edit****
I ran it through the terminal and this is the log:

```
    Node started time: 1493964352052
libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at Error (native)
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:158:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:568:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:169:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/node_modules/nodegit/dist/nodegit.js:11:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/appBootstrap/upgradeScripts/versionScripts/v1_5_0.js:7:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/appBootstrap/upgradeScripts/versionScripts/index.js:5:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/appBootstrap/upgradeScripts/index.js:7:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at EventEmitter.module.exports.app.on (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/appBootstrap/main.js:171:5)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

thanks.

Comment: Did you try to run `gitkraken` from terminal? Check the log error and edit your question.

Comment: is this question about Debian? why there is Debian tag to your question

Comment: The version of the gitkraken is .Deb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the log it seems like it is unable to find the libcurl shared library:

1) Try to install curl.

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3 php5-curl
```

2) If that doesn't work, try the command ldconfig (actualising libs)

3) If that too doesn't work :

- go to /usr/lib
- run find . | grep curl, locate the .so file (eg like curl_path.so or latest libcurl.so.xx)
- run ln -s {curl_path.so} /usr/lib/libcurl.so
- run ldconfig

Comment: can you explain what option 2 means?  is it just writing  "sudo ldconfig " inside the "gitkraken library"

Comment: ldconfig basically caches libs so that your programs with shared libs don't have to search the filesystem tree everytime they are run.  In this case, if for some reason the program wasnt able to search the libcurl, ldconfig helps.

Comment: It looks through all of the directories listed in /etc/ld.so.conf, finds
all of the shared libraries (*.so) in them, and creates a cache of all of
the libraries it found.  you can see which ones it found with 'ldconfig -v' 

The cache can be printed with `ldconfig -p'.